# Virtual machines VS Virtual Servers

Tags: server, virtual-machine, virtualization, virtual-server

I know that we can divide a server or a computer into many virtual machines using a `hypervisor` - but the question is how a **virtual machine** is different from a **virtual server**, or they are same thing?

Answer (score 1):

**Virtual Machine** :It is something which acts like a real computer with an OS.

**Physical Server**:It is a designated or used by single user and it is not shared by by multiple users.Each physical server has its own OS to run programs and application,memory hard drive,processors and network connection

But if we install a hypervisor on physical server we can create and manage virtual machine and then all these virtual machines will have their own resources, OS and server applications.

Then these virtual machines only can be used for different purposes and if they are used as a server then they are called virtual server.